# WotC Pre-rolled Level 1 Bard Character - Can't get it right in D&D Beyond

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, bard, dnd-beyond, pregenerated-characters

I'm trying to build the nifty 5E Half-elf Bard in D&D Beyond [as shared on WotC's set of pregen character sheets](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/character_sheets).

However, I just can't seem to get the ability score values and the skill values to align to what their character sheet PDF says and it's a real bummer.

Per their character sheet: STR 8 (-1), DEX 16 (+3), CON 14 (+2), INT 12 (+1), WIS 10 (0), and CHA 16 (+3).

And the Character Sheet skills are listed as: Arcana +3, Acrobatics +5, Deception +5, Insight +2, Perception +2, Performance +5 and Persuasion +5.

However, after entering in the ability scores they called out, my Deception is only +3 and my Insight is only 0. I got the rest to align though.

I've been at this for 90 minutes but to no avail. Any suggestions on how to make this match the sheet? Trying to make this one for my daughter as a surprise.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### It looks to me like you may have missed out adding character background

A 'background' adds two extra proficiencies to your character, so missing that out would account for the shortfall you've currently got on Deception and Insight.

It's also very easy to miss this part of character creation on DnD Beyond - it's slightly hidden away under section four of character creation titled 'Description'.

The character that you are trying to create (if you're copying the pre-gen exactly) should have the 'Entertainer' background which grants proficiency in Acrobatics and Performance. The fact that these are not the skills you're missing leads me to think that you've already picked those two as part of either your class / racial proficiencies.

#### There are two ways you can fix this:

**Either**: As you've already picked Acrobatics and Performance elsewhere DnD Beyond will give you a free choice of proficiencies as part of your Entertainer background instead - so so can select Deception and Insight there.

**Or**: If you'd prefer, you can unselect Acrobatics and Performance in the place where you've already selected them and select Deception and Insight there instead - then, once applied, your Entertainer background should default back to giving you Acrobatics and Performance.

#### An alternative is that you've missed adding your racial proficiencies

As a half elf you're also granted two proficiencies from your race - if you've missed adding these proficiencies then simply go and select Insight and Deception there to fix your issue. I consider this the less probable solution as it's harder to miss, whereas the 'Description' section, where you find background selection, could be overlooked and assumed to only contain 'fluff', rather than mechanics.

Bard's also get three proficiencies as a class feature - but as you're missing two, rather than three proficiencies, it seems to me unlikely that you'll find your error there.

Comment: @BensRPGPile Hi Ben - Glad to be of service. If you'd like to ask another question then the best way to do that on this platform is to ask it seperately - there's no penalty for opening multiple questions here. This site's format is based around asking clear questions and answers - so asking new questions in the comments is generally discouraged and is likely to be deleted by a moderater.

Comment: Roger that. Good to know. I will delete my comment as I actually did find the answer to it (e.g. single purchases do indeed get credited). You were totally right though! I bought the Entertainer Background and then added Deception and Insight and tah-dah! Skill scores indeed match the WotC Sheet. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple answer, If it is an ability or feature from a thing you dont have equipped or bought, you can manually change your stats.